# How to vertically center text in a round division?

Tags: html, css

I have created a round division which has text inside it. Problem is text stick to the top of circle I want text to be vertically centered. My text won't be long than 5 characters.

```css
.circle {
     background-color:#000;
     color:white;
     height:150px;
     width:150px;
     border-radius:50%; 
}
```

```html
<center><div class='circle'>hello</div></center>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define  this property

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
```

```css
.circle { 
     background-color:#000;
     color:white;
     height:150px;
     width:150px;
     border-radius:50%;
     text-align:center;
     display:table-cell;
     vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<center><div class='circle'>hello</div></center>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Line-height` to make it vertically center.Nike to make text vertical center make line height equal to its height.

```css
.circle {
    background-color:#000;
    color:white;
    height:150px;
    line-height:150px;
    width:150px;
    border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<center><div class='circle'>hello</div></center>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle:

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e4Lapyo8/)

Just need to display as a table cell and define its vertical alignment

```
.circle {
    background-color: #000;
    color: white;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used. Other centering methods are recommended.

As for centering the text in the circle, flexbox can do that:

```css
.circle {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='circle'>hello</div>
```